# Update MySQL global variable according to different user accounts?

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

How to change MySQL session global variable (i.e, SQL_mode, max_allowed_packet etc) for different user accounts. i have two users sam@localhost and joe@localhost i need to set different MySQL session variable values for both the users OR need to update the variable values when the user logged on is this possible??

Comment: See this thread for `SQL_mode`: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31447/how-can-i-set-a-default-session-sql-mode-for-a-given-user  I'm not sure you can change `max_allowed_packet` per user as it's a server wide setting.  (there is a command line on the client, but I don't think it behaves the same way as server setting)

Answer (score 5):

You can't change a `GLOBAL` value per user. Any `GLOBAL` option can have just one value at a time. What if both users were logged in at the same time?

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html:

> To change the SQL mode at runtime, set the global or session sql_mode system variable using a SET statement:
>
> ```
> SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'modes'; 
> SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes';
> ```
>
> Setting
>   the `GLOBAL` variable requires the `SUPER` privilege and affects the
>   operation of all clients that connect from that time on. Setting the
>   `SESSION` variable affects only the current client. Each client can
>   change its session `sql_mode` value at any time.

You can't change the server-side value of `max_allowed_packet` per session. Each session inherits from the global value. Since MySQL 5.1.31 the session value is read-only. See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22891

So you should set the server-side value of `max_allowed_packet` to the greater value needed by any of your users.

You may set the *client's* value for max_allowed_packet, because the effective limit is the *lesser* of the server-side value and the client-side value.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet says:

> When you change the message buffer size by changing the value of the max_allowed_packet variable, you should also change the buffer size on the client side if your client program permits it.  The default max_allowed_packet value built in to the client library is 1GB, but individual client programs might override this. For example, mysql and mysqldump have defaults of 16MB and 24MB, respectively. They also enable you to change the client-side value by setting max_allowed_packet on the command line or in an option file.

You don't say what client language your apps are using. Depending on the language and connector, there might not be a way to specify the max_allowed_packet as a client option.

Comment: one more i need to know is there any way to auto call a procedure or sql once the user logged on. i can set session variable (i.e, SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes';)  in the procedure once the user logged on it will set automatically.